# What a Fascinating Thing You Are

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

I've really enjoyed creating riddles lately, and I'm back with another one. This one should be simplistic enough, but who knows; maybe it'll stump you for a few minutes.

> My suffix is a ship; my prefix a pair.
>
> My infix is nonsense, of this I am aware.

What am I?

***Hint #1***:

> To find me is hard, and I'm trying to be fair; to assist in your search I am known as a bear.

***Hint #2***:

> I am known by my prey, which to find I must dig; in parts of the world I'm known as a pig.

Comment: This one "is stumping me for a few minutes"

Comment: That's the goal for this one. Took me a few minutes to think of a way to piece it together.

Comment: @Duck this one "is stumping me for much more than a few minutes" haha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you an

> [Aardvark?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUzoKbHABvI) (The clip attached is how I learned what the answer was, many years ago...)

My suffix is a ship; my prefix a pair.

> Suffix: ARK; Prefix: AA (pair of As)

My infix is nonsense, of this I am aware.

> Infix: RDV, which is pretty nonsense.

As for the hints,

> It is also known as the African ant bear; and aardvark is a Dutch compound word meaning earth pig or ground pig. Aardvarks are known for the ants that they eat, and apparently are [NOT anteaters](https://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/animals/photos/28-commonly-confused-animals/aardvarks-and-anteaters)!

Comment: What gave it away? I'm assuming it was the dual nomenclature?

Comment: The second hint made me think r13(nagrngre), which fit none of the prefix-suffix-infix clues; then by searching the second half of the hint, I learned that r13(nagrngref) and your answer aren't the same!

Comment: They are fascinating indeed; I think my favorite thing about them is that rot13(gurl unir gur genvgf bs zhygvcyr navznyf. Gurl unir gur rnef bs n enoovg, pynjf yvxr n onqtre, fabhgf yvxr cvtf, naq gurl ner vaperqvoyr qvttref pncnoyr bs zbivat 2sg bs qveg va 15 frpbaqf)!

Comment: Oh wow! That's really cool! Also completely unrelated (to the two above) but just as cool are the r13(cnatbyvaf)....I do love convergent evolution, it's always surprising how many different ways animals can do the same thing!

Comment: Those are actually really cool too! I've always loved the way they look. It's a shame that rot13(gurl ner urnivyl genssvpxrq); I can say that rot13(gurz fcenlvat sbhy yvdhvqf yvxr fxhaxf) is a new fact to me!

Comment: Yeah, they're battle-ready haha! I was surprised that they're able to walk bipedally using their tail to support them!

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Matchmark
> Def: a mark made on mating components of an engine, machine, etc, to ensure that the components are assembled in the correct relative positions

My suffix is a ship

> ark

My prefix a pair

> A match

My infix is nonsense, of this I am aware.

> m is indeed nonsense when left alone.

Comment: This was a great guess and taught me something new! +1

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Wilderness

My suffix is a ship;

> Referring to the SS prefix in boat names

prefix a pair

> It starts with a w(double u)

My infix is nonsense, of this I am aware.

> No idea, maybe the "nonsense" here is literal.

The hint:

> A bear symbol is commonly used to denote wilderness.

Edit: Shoot, I just saw the second hint. This is probably not the correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately no, but good attempt.

Answer (score 0):

2nd Attempt:

Are you a

> Panda?

My suffix is a ship

> NDA in shipping refers to Next-Day-Air. So this indeed is a type of ship.

My prefix is a pair

> A pair of peas (or p's). It's a play on words.

My infix is nonsense, of this I am aware.

> And can be nonsense, if used incorrectly, especially in this sense where it's P and A.

Hint:

> To find me is hard, and I'm trying to be fair; to assist in your search I am known as a bear.
>  Panda's are endangered species, and they are a type of bear.

Comment: This one was a long shot, but it made me laugh. I'll throw another hint up.